# Troubles using promise with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm currently working on an application based on **node.js**, the server side seems to be running properly but I'm having hard times with the public side.

I'm trying to use a ***promise*** with **AngularJS** in a **controller**. Here's my code :

```
var userId;
var userEmail = "somethingICanRecognizeInCaseItDoesntChange";

function getUserInfos(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(SessionStorageService.get('token')){
        Auth.isAlive().success(function(user){
            $scope.user = user;
            console.log("user :", user);
            console.log("user email :", user.email);
            deferred.resolve(user.email);
        });
    }
    else {
        $scope.user = {};
        deferred.resolve([]);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}

userEmail = getUserInfos();
console.log("result :", userEmail);
```

I thought that `result` in console would be the same as `user email`, but it's not.
Here's the console log :

```
result : Object { $$state: Object }
user : Object { firstName: "super", lastName: "admin", email: "a", isSuperAdmin: true, _ts: "2016-05-03T11:17:06.943Z" } website-ranking.js:41:21
user email : a
```

Here's a screenshot of what I get by clicking on `Object` in my browser console : [image: console]

The problem is, whatever I try, I never have `a` as result. I tried things like `getUserInfos().$$state`, `getUserInfos().$$state.value`, `getUserInfos().$$state.Object`, `getUserInfos().Object`, `getUserInfos().Object.value` and none of these worked.

What do I miss here ? Am I using promise in a wrong way ? Am I forgetting something ?

Please don't hesitate to tell me if this question can be improved, I'll gladly add code, or any informations you may need to help me solve my problem.

Edit : the thing is, I already used most of the code elsewhere, it's only since I added promise that I'm a bit lost. Here for example, I use the Auth.isAlive() without any problem :

```
function getUserInfos(cb){
            if(SessionStorageService.get('token')){
                Auth.isAlive().success(function(user){
                    $scope.user = user;
                    cb();
                });
            }
            else {
                $scope.user = {};
                cb();
            }
        }
```

The $scope.user is modified and usable further in the application with no issue.

As the question has been tagged as possible duplicate, I'd like to explain a bite more : I know why I'm using a promise, and I think I understood the differents issues with async in javascript. Here my problem is that my code doesn't work and I can't understand why, though I already successfully used promises in the past. I'm not asking how to get a response from async call, but a little help understand where I went wrong while writting code. If you still think that's a duplicate, let me know in comments and I'll deal with it, it's possible that I missed something in the link provided.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the callback needed for your Auth.isAlive function. The object you are looking at doesn't look like a proper response and might mean the function returns multiple parameters

Comment: Joe Clay please check the last part of my edit, and tell me if you still think it's a duplicate or not.
@Stephn_R : It'd be weird that Auth.isAlive function causes my problem since I used it without any problem before, please check my edit.

Comment: Your request for getting the user it's using $http or $resource? Please provide the code of the Auth.isAlive method.

Comment: @kazu: Hm, I suppose that question isn't *quite* the same as this one, although they're very similar. The basic problem is the same, though - you're calling an asynchronous function, and expecting it to immediately return its result. In this case, it's actually going to return a promise. You ought to be using it in the form: `getUserInfos().then(function (email) { ... });`.

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia it's using $http.

Comment: @JoeClay I understand what you mean about the duplicate now, and yes I guess that we can consider it as a duplicate for someone who doesn't work on the projet. Should I delete the question then ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your method getUserInfos() returns a promise, you're able to do this:

```
var userId;
var userEmail = "somethingICanRecognizeInCaseItDoesntChange";

function getUserInfos(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(SessionStorageService.get('token')){
        Auth.isAlive().success(function(user){
            $scope.user = user;
            console.log("user :", user);
            console.log("user email :", user.email);
            deferred.resolve(user.email);
        });
    }
    else {
        $scope.user = {};
        deferred.resolve([]);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}

getUserInfos().then(function(_email){
  userEmail = _email;
  console.log("result :", userEmail);
});
```